# pyodbc on SQL Server - How can I do an insert and get the row ID back?

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc, django-pyodbc

I'm using pyodbc with SQL Server 2000.

I want to be able to insert a row and get the auto incremented row id value back?  Any ideas?

Here's what I have so far:

```
cursor.execute("insert into products(id, name) values ('pyodbc', 'awesome library')")
cnxn.commit()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sorry, I asked too soon, [it's addressed in their FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/FAQs#How_do_I_retrieve_autogenerated/identity_values?)

Use "SELECT @@IDENTITY".