# Trying to find last insert row ID; returned value is encrypted

Tags: python, odbc, pyodbc, pypyodbc

I'm using pypyodbc with SQL Server 2016.

I am trying to insert and grab the last id inserted into database following [another user's remarks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883722/pyodbc-on-sql-server-how-can-i-do-an-insert-and-get-the-row-id-back) but the returned value seems to be encrypted. Is there a way to decrypt it?

```
def executeSQL (command):
    connection = pypyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Native Client};'
                                    'Server=blah\blah;'
                                    'Database=Impact;'
                                    'uid=Admin;pwd=F$sfgdfgs99')
    cursor=connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(command)
    id = cursor.execute("SELECT @@IDENTITY")
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()
    return id

sqlexecute = 'INSERT INTO PERSONS([LastName], [FirstName]) VALUES(\''+lastname.encode('utf-8')+'\',\''+firstname.encode('utf-8')+'\');\n'
lastid = executeSQL(sqlexecute)
print lastid
```

Output:

```
<pypyodbc.Cursor instance at 0x000000000B870C88>
```

Comment: A few notes in addition to the answer: you may want to alias `@@IDENTITY` - in fact, use `SCOPE_INDENTITY` for better scope accuracy. Try: `id = cursor.execute("SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS id")` Details on why you want to do this: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/ I'd also recommend using bound parameters for your `INSERT`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32748982/does-pyodbc-support-any-form-of-named-parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not encrypted, it is telling you the type of the object that this is an instance of. In this case, it is `pypyodbc.Cursor`.

To fetch the actual rows, you do `id.fetchall()` which will return a list of the results. You can then loop over them to read the contents.